# Calling Same Method Multiple Time from Different tabs With Different Parameters Value, But Getting first response only

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I had written Code in **Asp.net 6.0** With Swagger and now I am trying to call this method AS API From different Project with different Parameters continuously to check responses for different Parameters.

Below is the method:

```
 [HttpGet("GetdataPostv2")]
 public async Task<ActionResult> GetDataPostv2(string Source)
 {  
     return Ok(Source);
 }
```

I am trying to call this method using below urls from my local system and with different tabs and different **Source Parameters**.

```
https://localhost:44305/api/v1/rest/en-us/post/portal/GetdataPostV2?Source=1
https://localhost:44305/api/v1/rest/en-us/post/portal/GetdataPostV2?Source=2
https://localhost:44305/api/v1/rest/en-us/post/portal/GetdataPostV2?Source=3
https://localhost:44305/api/v1/rest/en-us/post/portal/GetdataPostV2?Source=4
https://localhost:44305/api/v1/rest/en-us/post/portal/GetdataPostV2?Source=5
```

Getting response like below:
[image]

I tried different TasK Methods of .net core and also tried to Use different techniques but unable to find the solution.
I want to execute same method with different parameter in source at same time. So, I can get different Results from API call at same time.

Comment: When testing with a simple new webapi , the source is shown correctly . https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGhwo.png 
Could you share your code more detailed like the middleware . Did you check the httpclient message ? According to your  endpoint name , the version could be a cause too .